# hook for block manipulation

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am developing a theme implementing bootstrap and looking for hook to wrap the block.

All the blocks for example:

```
<div id="block-blockname-blockname-block"
         class="block block-blockname contextual-links-region">
    ...
</div>
```

I want to wrap it dinamically with a hook, like this:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">

<div id="block-esp-csecundario-esp-csecundario-block"
         class="block block-esp-csecundario contextual-links-region">
    ...
</div>
</div></div>
```

I don't know which hook is needing for this block manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

looking into drupal hooks official info found "hook_block_view_alter" and implemented like this.

```
function mytheme_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if(isset($data['content']) && drupal_is_front_page() &&
                      is_string($data['content']) && !empty($data['content'])){
    $data['content'] =  '<div class="row row-wrap">' .
                        '<div class="col-lg-12 col-wrap">' .
                        $data['content'] .
                        '</div></div>';
  }
}
```

I filtered because throws several inecessary blocks.

Comment: you could also add the html to the region in the .tpl.php file

Comment: yes, i tried but the blocks are generated dinamically by Drupal and I couldn't, Thanks a lot.